# How to get value from second level Json keys in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm beginner in programming and really need your help with problem in Python.

I have python script like this:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://192.168.1.194/status/relay/')
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent = 4))
```

Which generate in cmd list like this

```
{
    "wifi_sta": {
        "connected": true,
        "ssid": "Network 3",
        "ip": "192.168.1.194",
        "rssi": -60
    },
    "cloud": {
        "enabled": true,
        "connected": false
    }
```

I'm fighting since yesterday to reduced response to one information - to status in row "enabled" : **true**
How I have to change code to get only word "true" from key "cloud" subkey "enabled" ?

I know how to get key cloud with two subkeys but I don't have any idea how to get value from subkey "enabled".

Thank you for answers..

Comment: `variable['cloud']['enabled']`

Comment: What makes you think nested keys are any different from top-level keys?

Comment: I can't solve problem whit this link on the top. When I type command  response.json().get('cloud') I get list like this {'enabled': False, 'connected': False}.  I tried with variable['cloud']['enable'] but I don't know where I have to put it, I got errors